# "Download from" vs. "download off"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, collocation, internet

> - I usually download music **off** the web.
> - I usually download music **from** the web.

What is the difference in between *off* and *from* in these sentences?

Which one is more suitable in this context?

Comment: Either sounds OK to me.  There is no real difference.  Yes, "off" and "from" are different prepositions, but the way they are used in this instance denotes the same thing:  the world wide web is the source of the music you are downloading.  You are getting music off the web or from the web.  Again, either is OK.

Comment: Agreed. If there is any distinction at all, I would say "from" is marginally preferable here, if only because "off" suggests that the thing being taken "off" was originally "on" in a fairly physical way (like a hat on a person), and that's not _quite_ how music exists in regard to the web; it's more "within" the web. (These are subtle and somewhat artificial distinctions, admittedly.)

Comment: What about this?
I got the book off Helen...
I got the book from Helen I got the book off the shelve...
I got the book from the shelve

Answer (score 2):

"Off" implies it was taken away or removed, but realistically it was probably copied. "From" makes best sense.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I feel more strongly than the other commenters here that *from* is far and away the most appropriate preposition.

*Off* is far more colloquial, and in my experience frequently inappropriate for the context in which it is used. This would be one of those contexts; I would take *off the internet* to mean literally *disconnected from the internet*, which naturally precludes downloading anything.

As a software developer, I frequently find myself in situations where it is unavoidable or even necessary to isolate a machine from its local network or the wider web. Speaking naturally, if a friend or colleague were to say 'off the web' I would usually decipher their intended meaning from the context but edge cases like this highlight why it is unnecessary to introduce ambiguity where it can be easily avoided.

Frankly, even *I download music **on** the web* would be more accurate than '...*off*...'.